# Porque é que os encontros consonantais "dl, sl, vl" (slogan, Vladimir, etc.) não existiam no português?

Tags: fonologia

Abundam no português os encontros consonantais inseparáveis ***bl, cl, fl***, etc., como em:

> **bl**indar, **cl**ima, **fl**or, **gl**aciar, **pl**uma, **tl**im-**tl**ão.

Depois há uns que parecem não existir: *dl, jl, ml, nl, rl, vl, xl, zl*. Muitos destes, imagino que não existam porque seriam difíceis de pronunciar. Aliás, também me parecem não existirem no inglês e francês. Mas ***dl*** nem me parece difícil, e existe no inglês. E depois há o ***sl***, que não existia no português, mas que se pronuncia tão bem que até entrou recentemente sob a forma de palavras estrangeiras importadas:

> **Sl**alom, **sl**ide, **sl**ip, **sl**ogan.

Mesmo o ***vl*** parece-me fácil de pronunciar, e já há por aí criançada com o nome *Vladimir*.

A inexistência no passado destes encontros consonantais terá sido mero acidente histórico? Ou há uma razão inteligível para a sua inexistência, especialmente do **dl, sl** e **vl**, no português?

Comment: Quais palavras francesas? E esses pares existiam no latim?

Comment: @Artefacto: "Palavras francesas"?! Não sei se existiam no latim. Mas mesmo que não tenham existido, tenho esperança que exista explicação melhor para não existirem no português. Isto é capaz de obedecer a umas regularidades fonéticas quaisquer.

Comment: Ooops, não li o _não_,

Comment: Acho que *jl* existe em palavras como *deslizar*.

Comment: @DanGetz Existe mas é separável: *des-li-ar*; a contrário, por exemplo, de *de-cli-nar*, em que o *cl* não pode ser separado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar da abundância dos encontros consonantais com ⟨l⟩ no português, para mim o vocabulário do português é marcado por certas faltas deles que se transformaram em *ch*: *chamar* (/kl/), *chama* (de fogo; /fl/), *chorar* (/pl/), *chumbo* (/pl/), *cheio* (/pl/), *chão*  (/pl/), *chuva* (/pl/), etc. Mas isto aconteceu antigamente e não representa nenhum proibição agora.

Acho que o que seria difícil para pronunciar tem muito a ver com a experiência de cada pessoa. Eu por exemplo acho encontros consonantais como /dl/, /tl/, /dv/, e /ʃks/ (sem falar do [[dʃpg]](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=s0102-44501998000100002&script=sci_arttext)) difíceis de pronunciar, talvez porque não existem na minha língua materna, o inglês. (Por exemplo, *bed-lam* e *ad-vise* são divididos.) Mas sei que outras pessoas têm menos dificuldade com eles.

Me parece que /dl/, /sl/, e /vl/ não aparecem no português principalmente devido à **sua falta no latim**, fonte da maioria das palavras portuguesas.

De acordo com [Phonology: Critical Concepts in Linguistics, Volume 4](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5_a3j_SAC7EC&pg=PA281&dq=%22in%20an%20obstruent-resonant%20cluster%20the%20resonant%20must%20be%20a%20liquid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEzbKhy8LiAhUQ8hoKHbuqAvIQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20an%20obstruent-resonant%20cluster%20the%20resonant%20must%20be%20a%20liquid%22&f=false) (p 281), no latim existiam só /pl/, /kl/, /bl/, /gl/ e /fl/. Aqui não aparecem /dl/, /sl/, /vl/, nem /tl/. (Por exemplo, *atleta* /a-tlɛ-tɐ/ vem do [*athleta*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/athleta) /atʰ-le-ta/.) A falta de /tl/, /dl/, /sl/, e /sr/, e a presença de /tr/ e /dr/, é considerado por os autores "sem dúvida 'sistemática' em vez de 'acidental'" e é explicado com uma regra (tradução minha):

> Num encontro obstruente-ressoante, a ressoante tem de ser uma líquida; mais ainda, se a obstruente for dental, ela tem de ser oclusiva e a líquida tem de ser /r/.

Em termos do /vl/, é importante lembrar que no latim clássico não havia /v/. A letra ⟨u⟩ podia ser /u/ ou /w/. Acho /wl-/ muito difícil de pronunciar. Não existe no português moderno, e não segue o ["Sonority Sequencing Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonority_Sequencing_Principle), porque as semivogais (como /w/) são mais sonorosas que as líquidas (como /l/).

---

Encontrei outra análise em [The Phonology of Portuguese](https://books.google.com/books?id=Onr9OFylajYC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=sonority%20scale%20portuguese&source=bl&ots=q-H5Yzam2Y&sig=m-VYxIYy7WvqItt8tx7SK9S3_WI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju8a2l8dTKAhUGbD4KHYHkBKQQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=sonority%20scale%20portuguese&f=false) (p 41–42). Aqui se fala do "Dissimilarity Condition" que torna difícil no português encontrar uma fricativa antes de /r/ ou /l/. Isto quer dizer que uma língua prefere ter bastante diferença em termos de sonoridade entre os consoantes num encontro consonantal, e que fricativas e líquidas não têm o bastante para o português. A evidência é a inexistência, na maioria das palavras portuguesas, de /sr/, /zr/, /ʃr/, /ʒr/, /vl/, /sl/, /zl/, /ʃl/ e /ʒl/, e a suposta raridade de /fr/, /fl/ e /vr/.